# ASP.NET MVC AZURE - make zip file from cloudblobdirectory of more than 650MB and uploading that zip as a Blob

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, zip, blob

I  am working on Azure Asp.net MVC web app. I have bolb directory of 755MB and i want to make it zip and want to upload zip file as blob. Kindly please suggest, how i  can do this?   i have tried to use DOTNETZIP and downloading all the blobs under than blob directory and adding those one by one in to zip.then i save zipfile to zipstream and use parallel upload by dividing into chunks to upload complete file as zip blob. it is working fine. but when it comes to run under azure environment, process stops and session timeout occurs. it does not throw any exception and in local code works perfectly fine. please help me.